# how to call a javascript function from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to read selected option (month) from mysql database via tabela.php (php then selects only users and their hours for he month selected). At this moment when i select a option i get results but it is shown in new site which is tabela.php. How can i make ajax or script to show me results on my HTML site.

For example: table on html is first empty, user then selects Januar and below that selection table should autofill with correct results.
HTML:

```
<form action="tabela.php" method="post">
Mesec: <select name="meseci", onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="o"> </option>
<option value="1">Januar</option>
<option value="2">Februar</option>
</select><br><BR>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('tabela.php');
}, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
```

php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$x = (isset($_POST['meseci']) ? $_POST['meseci'] : null);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ime, stevilo_ur FROM smart_ure WHERE mesec = '$x ' ");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ime</th> 
<th>stevilo_ur</th>
</tr>";
while ( $db_v = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $db_v['ime'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $db_v['stevilo_ur'] ."</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);

if (isset ($_GET['update']))
{
echo $tbl;
die ();
}
```

EDITED:

```
<form method="post" id="test_form">
Mesec: <select id="meseci">
<option value="o"> </option>
<option value="1">Januar</option>
<option value="2">Februar</option>
</select><br><BR>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
$(document).on('change','select[#meseci]',function(){
$post('tabela.php',$('#test_form').serialize()).done(function(results){
$('#results').html(results);
});
});
></script>
<div id="results"</div>
```

Comment: call PHP from JS is logic .. Opposite is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider you have `div` in your current page with `id=result`. Now, in your script file you can use `onChange()` on the `select` tag to get the data using ajax.
**JS script:**

```
$(document).on('change','select[name="meseci"]',function(){
    $.post('tabela.php',$('#test_form').serialize()).done(function(result){
        $('#result').html(result);
    });
});
```

Add id to your form, in above script I have used `id=test_form`.

```
<form action="tabela.php" method="post" id="test_form">
```

**Update your form tag:**

```
<form method="post" id="test_form">
```

Also, remove `onChange` from your select tag.

```
<select name="meseci">
```

Comment: I keep getting thrown on my tabela.php site, the results not showing on my html.

Comment: remove `action attribute` tag from your form

Comment: If i remove onchange how can i use the to POST a value to php?

Comment: `$(document).on('change','select[name="meseci"]',function(){});` will take care of it. This is a listener which listens to change event on the select having name = meseci.

Comment: I would suggest adding id to your select and use it to attach listener. for eg., if you add `id="meseci"` in your select tag, replace `select[name="meseci"]` with `#meseci`

Comment: Check my edit please. I am not getting the table shown. Can not find out what am i missing here.

Comment: `<select id="meseci" name="meseci">` update your select tag to this. PHP use name and not id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120900/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-jan).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @jaysingkar we got it to work. Below is the answer:

```
<form method="post" id="test_form">
Mesec: <select id="meseci" name="meseci">
<option value="o"> </option>
<option value="1">Januar</option>
<option value="2">Februar</option>
</select><br><BR>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
}); 
$(document).on('change','#meseci',function(){ 
$.post('tabela.php',$('#test_form').serialize()).done(function(result){ 
$('#result').html(result); 
});
}); 
</script>
<div id="result"</div>
```